# Glass Fish 3 connection refused - Netbeans IDE 8

Tags: java, glassfish-3, netbeans-8

I am trying to connect to glassfish server but everytime I run the pre written program I get this error. I have followed installation of netbeans and glassfish 3 correctly and have set up the server so I'm out of ideas. The error is below. Thanks a lot!

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
Can't join the chat roomjava.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
    at guiclient.ChatRoom.<init>(ChatRoom.java:30)
    at guiclient.GuiChatClientMain.main(GuiChatClientMain.java:17)
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be the problem that your connection port is occupied. try to change the connection port number and connect again. find th Domain.xml file in the directory \glassfish-3.0\glassfish\domains\domain1\config and change the port no 8080 to any other like 9999 in following line -

```
<network-listener name="http-listener-1" port="8080" thread-pool="http-thread-pool" transport="tcp" protocol="http-listener-1"/>
```

close the file and restart the glassfish server and re run your program.

Comment: Same issue, I even deleted the server and recreated it.